# noob - install wireless but need internet

Tags: drivers, usb

Just installed Ubuntu and now I want to install driver for a wireless USB adapter:

LB-Link BL-LW06-AR 300 Mbps USB Wireless N Adapter

Their driver needs to be compiled.

I type

> make

..It says 'apt install make'.  I type that.

..It says : Package 'make' has no installation destination

> sudo apt update

...and I get errors about 'Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

BECAUSE I don't have the internet, right?  I'm trying to get my wireless stick working, so I'm in an unhappy cycle here.

----If anyone has the compiled driver or any advice, I appreciate it.

Peter

Comment: Ubuntu comes with standard drivers and your wifi adapter should work out of the box.  Have you tried unplugging it and plugging it back in?  Compiling a driver is not as simple as typing `make`.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` with the device inserted. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Without network access, how did you get the source code to compile?